# Confused About Map Updates

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps

I'm *very* new to using Google Maps and *very* new to intricate javascript.  Bearing this in mind, I'm trying to create a web map, with a feed from USGS.  This feed is updated every 5 minutes.  I'd like to have my map refresh every 5 minutes using this same feed (which is a geojson file).

My end goal is to have this and at least one other feed displayed/updated on my map.  Over the past four days, I've gone through dozens of posts, and am at the point of being overloaded and confused.  Will someone please clear my fog?

The code I'm posting is 99% not my code, mostly I've added comments so I can figure out what's going on in the code.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>TEST OF MAP</TITLE>
    <STYLE>
/* --------------------------------------------------- */
/* Set the map height explicitly to define the size of */
/* the DIV * element that contains the map.            */
/* ----------------------------------------------------*/
      #map {
        height: 75%;
        border: 5px solid green;
      }
    </STYLE>
  </HEAD>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">    

// --------------------------------------
// Set a refresh interval in milliseconds
// --------------------------------------
    setInterval(page_refresh, 1*60000); 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</SCRIPT>

  <BODY>
    <H1><CENTER>MAP Demo</CENTER></H1>
    <DIV id="map"></DIV>

    <SCRIPT>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.4437,139.6380),
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Create a <SCRIPT> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
// ---------------------------------------------------------
        var script = document.createElement('script');

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Using a local copy of the GeoJSON stored on the USGS server
// 

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_hour.geojsonp
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        script.src = 

'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_hour.geojson

p';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Loop through the results array and place a marker for each set of
// coordinates.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
      window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
    </SCRIPT>

    <SCRIPT async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?

key=MY_MAP_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </SCRIPT>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What is your question?  What is the issue with the posted code?

Comment: Sorry, I thought my question was clear.  It was, but only in *my* head.  My apologies. It seems that the setInterval is not working, and I do not know why.  The only way I confirmed it was to do a manual refresh of the page long after the set refresh time limit was passed.  What can I do to get the page to refresh?  Thanks for any/all assitance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not very elegant, I used the following for the refresh. Since I'm only building a "proof of concept", refreshing the entire page is not a problem.

```
   function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
   }
   window.onload = timedRefresh(60*5000);
```